# How to change bootstrap's default sizes for the keywords xs sm md lg?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

According to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options, the default cutoffs for xs, sm, md, lg are cut off at 768px, 992px, and 1200px.

Can I still use those columns keyword classes like `.col-xs-3` without having the widths at which different sizes (e.g. xs sm md lg) are triggered at?

For example, I want xs cutoff point to be 420px instead of 768px, while still being able to use `.col-xs-3` (instead of having to define custom column widths)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page on the Bootstrap Documentation. You can change the Media Query breakpoints and generate a custom version of Bootstrap.

Comment: What is the best way to achieve this if you're using bootstrap-sass gem for rails?

Comment: or a cdn, as opposed to hosting it yourself.